# Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Tags: php, apache, joomla

I am facing the above problem frequently now a days for many of our sites.These were working properly about one month ago but suddenly more than 10 sites are giving this error not only in crome but in other browser also(not same but related).

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

All sites are hosted in the same server and in joomla.When I tried to debug I found that maybe the preblem is in the below code but not sure..

```
modMainMenuHelper::render($params, 'modMainMenuXMLCallback');
//render function
function render(&$params, $callback){
//function body
}
```

If I echo anything above `modMainMenuHelper::render($params, 'modMainMenuXMLCallback');` the output echo.But below `function render(&$params, $callback){` the above error comes.I wanted to ask if the problem is really in the above code than how to resolve this or any other suggestions that can solve this problem
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a server related problem to me, I would contact your systadmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I have solved the problem by disabling the APC module.Because it was causing the segmention fault.And whenever I updated the above file not the code the site started working properly.I hope this may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

`APC` or `pagespeed` on the server side can be the problem... 
if using `fcgi`, maybe there s a link to it. After a software update things can get messed up in the configuration....

since it happened after a certain date this should not be a issue of the application.