# Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) when posting from PHP page or to PHP page

Tags: php, linux, post

This morning we found an issue with many of the pages on our website when trying to submit a form. If the form is on a PHP page, or submitting to a PHP page, we would receive an error "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)".

I have two examples. One an HTML page submitting to itself, another a PHP page submitting to itself.

http://fun2dip.com/query.html
http://fun2dip.com/query.php

The HTML page submits without problem, the PHP page receives the above error. The pages are identical other than their extension. There is no PHP code on either page.

If I change the FORM method to GET, both forms work.

Our host is GoDaddy. We have tried troubleshooting the problem with them. They tell us it is a coding or scripting problem, and that everything on their end is fine. They can't help us anymore with the issue unless we can describe the exact problem, which we obviously can't because we have no idea what it is.

Any help is appreciated.

Below is the PHP version of the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="str">Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Name" size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="str">E-mail: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Email" size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" colspan="2"> &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to add the code?

Comment: If you want help with your problem, you'll have to show us your code. Without that, it's like trying to find a broken black box in the dark.

Comment: Your above code is plain HTML, not PHP.

Comment: So you don't have any PHP in there, just a HTML form that submits back to itself? And it's fine when it loads initially, but when you click submit, it crashes? Do you have access to the server error logs? Can you also try turning on PHP error reporting, too?

Comment: Like I explained, there is no PHP on the page. The problem comes from pages with the .php extension it seems. The two example links I posted are identical other than their extension.

Comment: Normally with PHP forms, if there's nothing related to PHP, something is bound to go wrong. Do you have your actual `PHP` code to show us? I can't make heads or tails out of something I can't see.

Comment: We're on GoDaddy shared hosting. We don't have direct access to any server error logs. I might be able to request them, I don't know yet.

Comment: @Konrad - could you try explicitly adding an `"action"` to the form?

Comment: @andrewsi - Sure, I added an action to the form.

Comment: @Konrad - And the error's the same?

Comment: @Konrad - that's.... odd. My suggestion would be to do a bare-bones form - just the `<form>` tag and a submit button, and see if it made a difference. It definitely looks like it's a server configuration issue, but it's not one I've ever seen before.

Comment: @Konrad I noticed your source's action is `query.php`. That won't work because it's the same page and not to an actual `mailer` handling script. Unless, `query.php` has code inside that you're not showing us.

Comment: @andrewsi - Here is a bare bones version with just the <form> tag and submit button. http://fun2dip.com/barebones.php. Still seems to have the issue.

Comment: @Fred - With my query.php page I'm trying to demonstrate that pages with a .php extension crash when submitted. This demonstration does not involve any mailer script.

Comment: @Konrad - it's not .php files per se, otherwise the initial file wouldn't load, but it's when you try to post to them. It's definitely something funky in the configuration, but I don't know enough to say any more - maybe you can add this question on serverfault and see if there's anyone there who knows more?

Comment: @Konrad Did a bit of digging for you, might be a memory related issue. See the links in the accepted answers for possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159602/error-324-neterr-empty-response - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394254/strange-error-on-increasing-memory-limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a few days on this and pulling out a lot of hair, I eventually was able to get a hold of a tech at GoDaddy who found that the issue was caused by something on their side. They never explained exactly what, and it took a few more days for them to fix. We have since moved the website off of GoDaddy.

Ultimately there was nothing wrong with our code. The issue was on GoDaddy's end.